# Android Studio crash at startup

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Just installed Android Studio (on the 9th Feb 2015) and I can't get past the startup as it crashes providing the following error - any ideas?:

Version of Android Studio (available in the about box):v1.0 
OS version: Windows 7 (64-bit) 
Java JRE/JDK version: JDK v1.8.0

Internal error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:159)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at Java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
```

Answer (score 1):

One options is to reinstall the Android Studio and imported settings from previous instance. So the project locations will not lost and can update the Android Studio too.